# phpmyadmin failing to query

Tags: php, mysql, percona

I have a 2 tables in 1 database. One has a list of postcodes with associated latitudes and longitudes (1758226 rows of data), and the other has client names and postcodes (45499 rows - some duplicated). I'm trying to query the two tables to give me a list of lat/long's for each client postcode.

I've tried a straightforward query:

```
SELECT postcodelatlng.latitude, postcodelatlng.longitude, address.postcode, address.company 
FROM postcodelatlng, address 
WHERE address.postcode LIKE postcodelatlng.postcode
```

I've tried this as well:

```
SELECT DISTINCT postcodelatlng.`postcode`, address.`postcode`, address.`company` 
FROM address 
    LEFT JOIN postcodelatlng ON postcodelatlng.`postcode` = address.`postcode`
```

I've upped the  memory_limit in php.ini from 128M to 512M, but that didn't work. I just keep getting 500 error in phpmyadmin.

If I limit the query to 100, it will work for those first 100 rows of results. Get passed a limit of 500 and it will error every time! I feel that it is a memory issue. Am I doing this wrong? The postcodelatlng table has and ID field which is a Primary Key, and the company table has 28 fields with a Primary Key for Company ID. Neither of these are referenced in the queries, but I thought I'd include this info for clarity.

Comment: Have you looked in the PHP Error log? and any other error logs??

Comment: Did you try `LIMIT 500,499` to check that you dont have a database corruption somewhere in the DB around row 500

Comment: Would indexes on the postcode columns help? And you could probably do `WHERE address.postcode = postcodelatlng.postcode`. You can check the status of your tables with: `SHOW TABLE STATUS;`.

Comment: _Small Point_ If you want columns with the same name from different tables you will need to add an alias to at least one of them like `postcodelatlng.postcode, address.postcode as addrpostcode,`

Comment: Does `SELECT postcodelatlng.latitude, postcodelatlng.longitude, address.postcode, address.company 
FROM address 
INNER JOIN postcodelatlng on postcodelatlng.postcode = address.postcode` have the same problem?

Comment: Thanks, you have given me a few things to try and to look at. I will let you know how I get on.

Comment: So...the only error log I could find was PHP_Fast_CGI_errors.log and I couldn't open it as it was too big (nearly 3GB - that's bad!). I have also noticed that the C drive disk space is being eaten at the rate of knots! I restarted the machine to reclaim 50GB of space that I used this morning in the last hour alone, running these queries in a variety of ways. The file that's bloating is the ibtmp1 file in C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Data.

Comment: I should also mention that I am running Percona. Not sure if this has any impact on anything TBH. On first try this morning of the query:

SELECT postcodelatlng.latitude, postcodelatlng.longitude, address.postcode, address.company FROM address INNER JOIN postcodelatlng on postcodelatlng.postcode = address.postcode

...that droopsnoot suggested (thanks BTW) it ran okay at a limit of 500. But carrying on with the same limit just errored, I think because the tmp file ran out of room. Surely the file shouldn't be getting this big with this relatively small query...should it?

Comment: Also, I couldn't index the postcode columns as this errored also. This must be a caching issue of some sort!?

Comment: No idea why, but the ibtmp1 file is remaining a sensible size now and the postcode columns indexed ok. I may be being a little dumb here, but do I need to reference the Index names in the query now, or do I just carry on as I was with referencing the tables and columns (with aliases of course)?